# Command line conversion of PDF to PDF/A on linux? Annotation problems with ghostscript

Tags: linux, pdf, pdfa

I have tried using ghostscript on linux to convert PDF documents to PDF/A.   But I run into the dreaded "Annotation set to non-printing, not permitted in PDF/A," problem.  The solutions for that, that I've found on the web, don't create PDF/A documents that can be verified by Verapdf.  Assuming that there is no solution for this issue, are there any alternative programs?  Free or single client affordable packages?  I would even consider a windows command line program, that perhaps I could run using Wine.  Thanks very much!

Comment: I figured out my problem.  I was using Ghostscript 9.10, which was the highest level available for the version of Ubuntu I was running.  Ghostscript 9.21 fixes the PDF/A incompatibility problems, so I'm now available to create real PDF/A files!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading ghostscript, fixed my problem.  9.10 is the highest level available on older versions of Ubuntu.   Upgrade to at least 9.20.